# Color and style manipulation on textview

Tags: android, string, colors, coding-style, textview

ok imagine that we have text like this

```
String s="123 45678 91011122314 1516";
```

now my problem is that I want so say

```
textview.setText(stylemystring(s));
```

and I want '123' to be bold and red, 45678 to be italic and blue, and so so

I find it quite problematic when styling these thing , there are solutions with htmlformat but the thing is that the size of the text that should be red or blue is dynamic so I need something more flexible.

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
    SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder("123 45678 91011122314 1516");
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 4, 9, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 4, 9, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

You can add different styles to different parts of the String. 
Based on http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to split it up in different strings to achieve that though.

Take a look at [this link](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring)

I think it has what you're looking for.